# In HAML on Ruby on Rails, how to use the :sass filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

If using HAML on Ruby on Rails, then

```
:sass
  #someDiv
    border: 3px dashed orange
```

won't have any `<style>` tag around them.

and then

```
:css
  :sass
    #someDiv
      border: 3px dashed orange
```

won't kick on the `:sass` filter, but

```
:css
:sass
  #someDiv
    border: 3px dashed orange
```

will kick on the `:sass` filter, but it is outside of the `<style>` tag.  So how can the `:sass` filter be used?  We can manually wrap `<style>` around it, but it is not common use that we want to generate css from sass but not inside `<style>` tag in an HAML file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation related to your question is [here](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/) at haml-lang.com and a more detailed explanation over at [sass-lang.com](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#rackrailsmerb_plugin).

I believe what you are missing is that sass should not be used in your haml files.  They should be placed in public/stylesheets/sass with a .sass extension.  They will be compiled into a .css file in public/stylesheets, which you then link into your layout.

From the sas-lang.com link:

> For instance, public/stylesheets/sass/main.scss would be compiled to public/stylesheets/main.css.

You would then use the [stylesheet_link_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#M002231) helper (or link the stylesheet manually):

```
<%= style_sheet_link_tag 'main' %>
```

If you really need to use sass within haml, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913150/using-the-sass-filter-with-css) is the answer.  You can not nest filters in haml.  You apparently need to do something like this:

```
%style(type="text/css") 
  :sass 
    div 
      color: red
```

I believe [this](http://groups.google.com/group/haml/browse_thread/thread/877ae2132053c951) was the original response from the haml google groups.

Comment: hm... if sass should not be used in an haml file, then the sass filter shouldn't have existed?

Comment: It has its uses, but using an external stylesheet tends to be more maintainable and DRY. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127927/is-using-the-style-attribute-frowned-upon

Comment: Sass/scss filter would be useful for example to have 404, 422 and 500 as pages with separate layout and caching turned on, so on deploy you just request pages somehow to get static html files. I just don't like to write plain css.

Comment: My use case: some basic styles should be editable by site admins during runtime. I store a bunch of variables in the database and all styles that use those variables go into a haml partial.

Answer (score 11):

[Since 4.0.0](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400),

> The `:sass` filter now wraps its output in a style tag, as do the new `:less` and `:scss` filters.

Before 4.0.0, just wrap it in `%style`:

```
%style
  :sass
    // so sassy! ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom filter to generate style tag also.

The example below defines a new ':csass' filter.

```
require "haml/filters"
module Haml::Filters::Csass
  include Haml::Filters::Base
  include Haml::Filters::Sass
  lazy_require 'sass/plugin'
  def render(text)
    src = super
    "<style>#{src}</style>"
  end
end
```

So you can do it like this :)

```
:csass
  #someDiv
    border: 3px dashed orange
```